# Loop alembic animation

Tags: animation, alembic

I have an 4 frame animation made in Maya that i need in blender. Alembic wokres fine, but stops after frame 4, since there is no more animation. Is there a way i could loop the alembic file in blender?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Related:

- [reverse alembic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212986/30849)
- [start alembic at specific frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79304/30849)

---

Once you imported an Alembic Cache, the object in Blender will have an Alembic Cache Constraint.

1. Check **Override Frame**.
   [image: alembic cache constraint]
2. In the **frame** property you can set keyframes.
    The following expression will loop through frame 1, 2, 3, 4. Directly enter the following in the Frame property:
   `#(frame - 1) % 4 + 1`

---

#### The Values used in the Python Expression

```
#(frame - <starting_frame>) % <animation_duration> + <starting_frame>

frame               the actual frame played
starting_frame      the frame id where the animation begins
animation_duration  the number of frames the animation lasts
```

To customize the driver to your needs, replace `starting_frame` and `animation_duration` with your values:

The animation starts at frame 1 and lasts 4 frames: `#(frame - 1) % 4 + 1`