# How to start imported Alembic animation at a specific frame

Tags: animation, alembic

How to? Imported .abc file starts at frame 1. I want it to start later.

Comment: Almost a duplicate. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78701/30849

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting it to work. After inserting the line in the Frame property the animation doesn't animate at all. Could you please explain that expression to me? My programming language skills are nonexistent.

Comment: EDIT: OK, I get it now, it is literally about setting the frames. No expressions needed. Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer for future reference. Also included some information about a possible alternate expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related

- [looping alembic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78701/30849)
- [reverse alembic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212986/30849)

---

> Once you imported an Alembic Cache, the object in Blender will have an Alembic Cache Constraint.

1. Check Override Frame.
   [image]
2. Go to your desired starting frame. Type `1` in the *Frame* property. Hover over the property and press <kbd>I</kbd> to set a key. Set a key on the next frame with the value of `2`. In the Graph Editor, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and select **Linear Extrapolation**. Then select the first keyframe, press <kbd>T</kbd> and make it a **constant** key.

---

## Using a python expression

Type the following expression in the frame property:

```
#(1 - round((frame - frame_offset)%0.99999)) * (frame - frame_offset) + frame_hold
```

Replace `frame_offset` with the desired starting frame. Replace `frame_hold` with the frame which is held before the starting frame. `frame` doesn't change, it is a python variable holding the current frame number.

Example. To achieve the following:

```
Frame     Calculated
11        2   |
12        2   |  The frame held before is no 2.
13        2   |
14        2   |
15        2   < This is the starting frame (15).
16        3
17        4
18        5
19        6
20        7
```

The expression would be:

```
#(1 - round((frame - 15)%0.99999)) * (frame - 15) + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gui solution works in 2.82. To clarify, in the frame box, 1 indicates frame 1 of the alembic animation that is keyframed into the timeline. The 2nd timeline keyframe should have the  last alembic animation frame number e.g. A 125 frame alembic animation is keyframed to start with the number 1 in the "frame" box at frame 100 and keyframed at framed as 125 at timeline frame 225.