# Imported an Alembic animation to Blender. How can i time-reverse it?

Tags: timeline

I imported an Alembic animation to Blender from the VR animation app Tvori. How can i time-reverse it? i need it to play as intended but then would like it to play backward, so to create a loop. and then render. is it even possible?
i'm a total beginner so i don't know anything about how the Blender timeline works, but coming from video editing it's hard for me to look at the timeline and not even see a clip on it that represent my "animation" and on which i can maybe right click and change settings? 
i know, i sound very ignorant about all of this which i am.

thank you for any response!

Comment: p.s: i'm using latest version of Blender, 2.8something

Comment: This should help. It's about looping an .abc cache, but you can make it play once in reverse with the same tools. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78674/loop-alembic-animation/78701#78701

Comment: thanks! but i have blender 2.8 so that menu is not relevant to my case :/ my "object" is an animation that is made of about 20 different objects, not just one. they came out in the alembic file all separated. and if i click on one and check the Constraint panel, nothing comes up, it just says to "Add Object Constraint".

Comment: 2.9 is the newest...

Answer (score 4):

Related:

- [looping alembic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78701/30849)
- [start alembic at specific frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79304/30849)

(e.g.) My alembic animation has a length of `240` frames.

1. Select all the objects, which were created on alembic import and go to the constraints or modifiers [properties tab].
2. Hold <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> and <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> click *Override Frame*.
3. Then <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> into the *Frame* field and type `# 240 - frame`.

A driver will be created for the *Frame* field and the field will turn purple.

Holding the <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> key ensures, that this happens in all the modifiers and constraints of all the selected objects. You can confirm this, by individually selecting the other objects and double-check that their *Frame* field of the Cache Modifier and Cache Constraint is also purple.

[image: steps]

Answer (score 0):

If you can render the animation frame by frame into images in "normal" order, once, then you can use the Video Sequencer to reverse an image strip and play it backward. This works for any animation you can render...